# Changing "/" into "\" in R

Tags: r, backslash, slash

I need to change "/" into "\" in my R code. I have something like this:

```
tmp <- paste(getwd(),"tmp.xls",sep="/")
```

so my `tmp` is `c:/Study/tmp.xls`

and I want it to be: `c:\Study\tmp.xls`

Is it possible to change it in R?

Comment: Have you tried `paste(..., sep="\\")` ?

Comment: it will change only "/" before tmp.xls, I will then have "c:/Study\tmp.xls" so still one "/" left

Comment: Why? R *does* access all paths just fine with the forward slash. Try it.

Comment: I need it while saving xls from R. And Office doesn't access paths with "/"

Comment: You misunderstand. Office only cares about how *it* reads the write.  For R to write it, forward-slashes are just fine, and in fact easier.

Comment: @Dirk - are you sure you are talking about SaveAs in RDCOMClient package ? R is opening Excel in this package and saving xls file using Save as in Excel. So "/" is important there.

Answer (score 11):

#### Update as per comments.

If this is simply to save the file, then as @sgibb suggested, you are better off using `file.path()`:

```
    file.path(getwd(), "tmp.xls")
```

#### Update 2: You *want* double back-slashes.

tmp is a `string` and if you want to have an actual backslash you need to escape it -- with a backslash. 
However, when `R` interprets the double slashes (for example, when looking for a file with the path indicated by the string), it will treat the seemingly double slashes as one.

Take a look at what happens when you output the string with `cat()`

```
cat("c:\\Study\\tmp.xls")
c:\Study\tmp.xls
```

The second slash has "disappeared"

---

#### Original Answer:

in `R`,  `\` is an escape character, thus if you want to print it literally, you need to escape the escape character: `\\`.   This is what you want to put in your `paste` statement.

You can also use `.Platform$file.sep` as your sep argument, which will make your code much more portable.

```
 tmp <- paste(getwd(),"tmp.xls",sep=.Platform$file.sep)
```

---

If you already have a string you would like to replace, you can use

```
    gsub("/", "\\", tmp, fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: But then I have "c:\\Study\\tmp.xls" - is it possible to change it into "c:\Study\tmp.xls" ?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta IMHO `tmp <- file.path(getwd(), "tmp.xls")` is the better solution.

Comment: But still - I have "/" and I need "\"

Comment: @Ania '\\' is '\'. If you were to write a string with this to file or pass it as an argument to another program, there would only be one backslash. The `print` function prefixes special characters with "\", so it may mistakenly lead you to think there are actually two backslashes. The `cat` function on the other hand will print strings as they actually are. Note what `cat('\\')` outputs.  Also note that `nchar('\\')` is one.

Comment: I am preparing xls file using The RDCOMClient package. And I want to save it (from R) using SaveAs. And I want to save it in working dorectory - but then I need exactly one \. If I put "c:\\Study\\tmp.xls" into SaveAs - Office won't recognize this path

Comment: Ania, @sgibb's recommendation is actually best

Comment: Ricardo, but it is not giving me "c:\Study\tmp.xls" as an output

Comment: @Ania that's kind of surprising. Is it an option for you to change R's working directory to the output directory with `setwd` and then simply pass the basename, tmp.xls, to SaveAs? Or is output created through RDCOMClient not relative to R's current working dir?

Comment: @Ania, to be clear, if you are trying to access the file (for writing etc) you do *not want "c:\Study\tmp.xls"*.   You **want to have double slashes**.  That is how `R` will access the file.

Comment: @Matthew, but I want the output directory to be R's working directory.   (I mean - I setwd R working directory as "c:\Study\" and want to save xls file just there). So I want R to take its working directory, change / into \ and than save xls file "c:\Study\tmp.xls"

Comment: @Ricardo, I don't want R to access a file. I want R to save xls file - so R will only paste filename into Office - and Office doesn't want double slashes. That is why I want to have single slashes.

Comment: @Ania, have you tried writing the string that contains two slashes?  The second slash will "disappear"

Comment: @Ania I feel like in order to resolve whatever problem you are having, you should either expand this question or make a new one with a simplified example of how exactly you're trying to write this file.

Comment: @Ricardo - it won't in Excel. Try opening Excel, choosing save as and pasting c:\\Study\\tmp.xls - it won't work. That is why I need c:\Study\tmp.xls\

Comment: @Ania, the point is that you are somehow getting the string "c:\\Study\\tmp.xls" to excel.  How is it getting there?  Perhaps open up a fresh question being more explicit about what you are doing?

Comment: library(RDCOMClient)
xls <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xls[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wb = xls[["Workbooks"]]$Add(1)
filename<-paste(getwd(),"tmp.xls",sep="/")

and now I want to do:
wb$SaveAs(filename)

but then I need filename to have "\".

Comment: @Ania, also, have you tried Dirk's suggestion?  It seems pretty spot on