# bookdown project: how to enforce code formatting via circleci?

Tags: r, r-markdown, circleci, bookdown

I'm writing a bookdown document with a small team in a private GitHub repo. I saw a hint that i could enforce code formatting (quotes, spaces, = instead of <- etc) with circleci.

I've looked for tutos and found [this](https://circleci.com/blog/enforce-build-standards/) for GO, but failed to find for R.

Any hints?

## EDIT

Clarifying the question:
What should the .yml file look like?

```
version: 2
jobs:
   steps:
     - run:
         name: "Enforce R style"
         command: "????????"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with GitHub actions:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

name: lint

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

      - name: Install lintr
        run: install.packages("lintr")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Lint

        run: lintr::lint_dir(linters = lintr::with_defaults(assignment_linter = NULL, line_length_linter = NULL, spaces_left_parentheses_linter = NULL), pattern = '[.]R$|[.]Rmd')
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645091/changing-into-in-r) is a link where they use gsub for regex. apologize I don't have  working example at the moment, but the [formatr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formatR/index.html) package might be able to help you with the spaces and quotes